"Saddle connection" on a translation surface

A saddle connection on a translation surface $\omega$ is a geodesic
in the flat metric determined by $\omega$ joining two zeros with no zeros in its interior.

Athreya, Jayadev S., and Howard Masur. Translation Surfaces. Vol. 242. American Mathematical Society, 2024. Quote from p.26.
Q. Why is it called a "saddle connection"? In particular, why saddle?

If you think of the zeros as cone points and imagine two cones pointing up with a saddle connection joining them, it really does look like a (horse) saddle.

@AndyPutman: That makes sense---Thanks!

https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/selle/monkeysaddle.gif
